# Microsoft Bot Framework project to add a chatbot to my website. I cannot use the Web Chat client. What other methods can I use ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bots, botframework, web-chat

I am working on a Microsoft Bot Framework project to add a chatbot to my website.
I need to pass data continuously from the chat UI to the Bot to get user details and current page details. Therefore I cannot use the Web Chat client.

What other methods can I use apart from creating my own chat interface ?

Answer (score 5):

> **What other methods can I use apart from creating my own chat interface ?** According to this statement, WebChat is the easiest way. Because only with an embeded Iframe you are done creating your chatbot. Apart from that,

There is a REST Api to access the botframework. It is called as Direct Line API. You can find documentation from,
[HERE](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/restapi-directline/)

Below is a code sample about how you can use it. I tried with the `ASP.NET MVC` application.

```
private async Task<bool> PostMessage(string message)
        {

        bool IsReplyReceived = false;

        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("BotConnector", "[YourAccessToken]");
        response = await client.GetAsync("/api/tokens/");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var conversation = new Conversation();
            response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/conversations/", conversation);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Conversation ConversationInfo = response.Content.ReadAsAsync(typeof(Conversation)).Result as Conversation;
                string conversationUrl = ConversationInfo.conversationId+"/messages/";
                BotDirectLineApproch.Models.Message msg = new BotDirectLineApproch.Models.Message() { text = message };
                response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(conversationUrl,msg);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    response = await client.GetAsync(conversationUrl);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        MessageSet BotMessage = response.Content.ReadAsAsync(typeof(MessageSet)).Result as MessageSet;
                        ViewBag.Messages = BotMessage;
                        IsReplyReceived = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        return IsReplyReceived;
    }
```

In here `Message, MessageSet and Conversation` are classes created by looking at the Json response in the documentation. If you need, I can add that also.

Cheers!